# Trying to get a listview item throws NoSuchElementException when using and iterator in Android

Tags: android, iterator

I have below piece of code:

```
    CustomArrayAdapter adapter;
    Set<Integer> checkedItems;
    Iterator<Integer> it;
    Model element;

    adapter = (CustomArrayAdapter) getListAdapter();
    checkedItems = adapter.getCheckedItems();
    it = checkedItems.iterator();

    int size = checkedItems.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        element = adapter.getItem(it.next());
        // Do whatever
    }
```

Trying to get listview item using adapter.getItem(it.next()) throws error NoSuchElementException.

In my concrete case, size is 1. Initially I set Iterator for first time outside for loop, so I guess it is placed at first element. In first iteration, I guess it.next() points to first element but it seems not as it throws the error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think the first item is `getItem(0)`.

Comment: Yes, if I use directly the for loop iterator index i for doing so adapter.getItem(i) then it works but using the iterator does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that the call `it.next()` returns the **next** object, meaning that if you start at 0, `it.next()` will return 1. Since your `ListView` only has 1 element in it, that element resides at index 0, not 1, which explains why you are getting a `NoSuchElementException`.

To fix this, you could call the `Iterator` method `hasNext`, which will return `true` if there is another element and `false` if there is not, before calling `element = adapter.getItem(it.next())`. Perhaps something like the following:

```
if (it.hasNext())
{
    element = adapter.getItem(it.next());
}
```

To handle getting the first element (index 0), you could do a simple check:

```
if (it.next() == 1)
{
    element = adapter.getItem(it.next() - 1);
}
```

Comment: but first time iterator should point to first element and not next. I understood that doing adapter.getItem(it.next()) it first return the current index and then it moves to next. So how to set iterator at first element if it does not work?

Comment: You could always just do `it.next() -1`. Out of curiosity, why are you using an iterator if there is only one item in your `ListView`.

Comment: In this case there is only an item, I am debugging my app, but more than one item can be there.

Comment: Understood. I updated my answer to help you handle getting the first element. After that it should be fine.

Comment: As you said by doing it.next() - 1 is working so replacing it in the for loop is working. The problem is that I think it.next() is not 0 based, its first element has index 1, second 2 and so on, but adapter.getItem() is 0 based, so first item should be 0, second 1, and so on... so when using it.next() it was returning index 1 for first item and it was necessary to be 0 for getItem, so substracting 1 unit, that is, it.next() - 1 is working. Also by using it.next() when collection has more than 1 item, first item will be skipped and trying to read last, probably will crash throwing out of bounds